# QGraphicsView измение размера мышкой. QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

Есть какое-то свойство, которое позволяет растягивать элемент мышкой?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например как в основной форме: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update**:
Добавляю QSizeGrip :

```
QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(ui->graphicsView_5);
```

Получается следующее, но растягивается не конкретно он, а получается все окно с пропорциональным увеличением всех элементов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в зависимости от того, что именно нужно можно воспользоваться `QSplitter`'ом, или `QDockWidget`'ом, или `QMDIArea`/`AMDISubWindow`...

Answer (score 1):

В Qt для этого есть отдельный элемент - [QSizeGrip](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizegrip.html), которому нужно передать в аргументах указатель на виджет, который нужно растягивать.

Comment: Создать этот объект и через него уже работать?

Comment: см. в описании)

Comment: был бы очень благодарен за пример именно с мои QGraphicsView

Comment: @Optimus, похоже я тебя не так понял. QSizeGrip предназначен для растягивания окна верхнего уровня. Если нужно растягивать отдельно каждый QGraphicsView, то, думаю, лучше их поместить в QDocWidget. А там уже реализовано растягивание.

Comment: Понял. А как то можно его обернуть в дизайнере, если нет, то как программно это реализовать?

Comment: QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
QDockWidget *doc = new QDockWidget;
 doc->setWidget(view);
 addDockWidget(Qt::DockWidgetArea::LeftDockWidgetArea, doc);